# How to get Q Values in RL - DDQN

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I'm not sure how to get the Q Values for a DDQN.

DQN is the normal network, TAR the target network.

```
    q_values = self.DQN.predict(c_states) # DQN batch predict Q on states
    dqn_next = self.DQN.predict(n_states) # DQN batch predict Q on next_states
    tar_next = self.TAR.predict(n_states) # TAR batch predict Q on next_states
```

I mainly found 2 versions:

**Version 1:**

```
q_values[i][actions[i]] = (rewards[i] + (GAMMA * np.amax(tar_next[i])))
```

**Version 2:**

```
act = np.argmax(dqn_next[i])
q_values[i][actions[i]] = (rewards[i] + (GAMMA * tar_next[i][act]))
```

Which one is correct? And why?

**Version 1 Links:**

https://github.com/keon/deep-q-learning/blob/master/ddqn.py

https://pythonprogramming.net/training-deep-q-learning-dqn-reinforcement-learning-python-tutorial

**Version 2 Links:**

https://github.com/germain-hug/Deep-RL-Keras/blob/master/DDQN/ddqn.py

https://github.com/rlcode/reinforcement-learning/blob/master/2-cartpole/2-double-dqn/cartpole_ddqn.py

https://jaromiru.com/2016/11/07/lets-make-a-dqn-double-learning-and-prioritized-experience-replay/

---

**EDIT:**
Many thanks, to clarify this

```
Q-learning: 
q_values[i][actions[i]] = (rewards[i] + (GAMMA * np.amax(tar_next[i])))

SARSA: 
act = np.argmax(dqn_next[i])
q_values[i][actions[i]] = (rewards[i] + (GAMMA * tar_next[i][act]))
```

**EDIT: re-open 03/2020**

I'm sorry but i have to re-open that question. Maybe I misunderstood something, but the following sources show that my Version 2 (SARSA) is Double Q Learning?

**Page 158 : Double Q-learning**
http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2018.pdf

[adventuresinML](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/double-q-reinforcement-learning-in-tensorflow-2/)

[adventuresinML source](https://github.com/adventuresinML/adventures-in-ml-code/blob/e661eeb5db86d2d0aa21621b68b5186d80e3d8b6/double_q_tensorflow2.py#L86)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your help and the informations here [leosimmons](https://medium.com/@leosimmons/double-dqn-implementation-to-solve-openai-gyms-cartpole-v-0-df554cd0614d), I found the source of my confusion:

The Bellman equation used here [Bellman equation - link 3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06461.pdf) follows the equation:

```
value = reward + discount_factor * target_network.predict(next_state)[argmax(online_network.predict(next_state))]
```

The Bellman equation in the **original** (vanilla) DQN [Bellman equation - link 2](https://storage.googleapis.com/deepmind-media/dqn/DQNNaturePaper.pdf) is:

```
value = reward + discount_factor * max(target_network.predict(next_state))
```

[leosimmons](https://medium.com/@leosimmons/double-dqn-implementation-to-solve-openai-gyms-cartpole-v-0-df554cd0614d)

> The difference is that, using the terminology of the field, the second
>   equation uses the target network for both SELECTING and EVALUATING the
>   action to take whereas the first equation uses the online network for
>   SELECTING the action to take and the target network for EVALUATING the
>   action. Selection here means choosing which action to take, and
>   evaluation means getting the projected Q value for that action. This
>   form of the Bellman equation is what makes this agent a Double DQN and
>   not just a DQN and was introduced in [3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06461.pdf).

[1](https://medium.com/@leosimmons/double-dqn-implementation-to-solve-openai-gyms-cartpole-v-0-df554cd0614d) https://medium.com/@leosimmons/double-dqn-implementation-to-solve-openai-gyms-cartpole-v-0-df554cd0614d

[2](https://storage.googleapis.com/deepmind-media/dqn/DQNNaturePaper.pdf) https://storage.googleapis.com/deepmind-media/dqn/DQNNaturePaper.pdf

[3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06461.pdf) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06461.pdf

Very well explained here:
https://youtu.be/ILDLT97FsNM?t=331

Answer (score 2):

This is Q-learning (the version with the max operator) vs SARSA (without the max).

In short, you collect samples using the e-greedy policy: this is your behavior (or exploration) policy. The policy you want to learn is called "target" and can be different.
With Q-learning, you use the max operator, so your target is chosen according to the greedy (target) policy. This is called off-policy learning, because you learn a policy (target) with the samples collected by a different one (behavior).

With SARSA, there is no max, so in practice you just use the action from the samples, that was selected by the behavior policy. This is on-policy, because the target and the behavior are the same.

Which one to prefer is up to you, but I think that Q-learning is more common (and DQN uses Q-learning).

More reading about this

[What is the difference between Q-learning and SARSA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848828/what-is-the-difference-between-q-learning-and-sarsa)

[Are Q-learning and SARSA with greedy selection equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846262/are-q-learning-and-sarsa-with-greedy-selection-equivalent)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184657/what-is-the-difference-between-off-policy-and-on-policy-learning

http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2018.pdf

**EDIT FOR DDQN**

SARSA and Q-learning are two separate algorithms.

In DDQN you have two target Q, and two target policies, so the algorithm is still off-policy (sampling policy is e-greedy, target policies are greedy), while SARSA is on-policy (target policy = sampling policy).

The trick in DDQN is that you use the max operator over Q2 (second critic) in the TD target for updating Q1 (first critic), and viceversa. **But there still is the max, so it's still off-policy. SARSA, instead, is on-policy.**

There are multiple versions of DDQN, some use the mininum over Q1 and Q2 for instance. Here are some references

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06461.pdf

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.09477.pdf

Comment: Sorry Simon, i had to edit my question, i found other sources with SARSA = DDQN? Can you clarify this please?

Comment: @anna12345 I have edited my answer.
I can't open the book right now (very slow internet), but I know DDQN (there are multiple versions of it) and I referenced two of the most prominent versions.

Comment: Sarsa has nothing to do with dqn/ddqn except they both are model-free, value-based algorithms. But that's it. @Simon explained they different by on/off-policy learning. It's like lion and zebra - both live in savannahs. Nobody would call them the same nonetheless.